# Bootstrap 3 Wordpress Starter Template

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, starter-kits

I design multilingual websites built using Bootstrap 3.  Our software is bespoke and written from the ground up by us.  However, we seamlessly integrate WordPress blogs into the sites and up until recently have been using a freebie from 320press which did the job ok - it's just for basic blogging and pulls in the css from the main site.  I'm now looking for something a bit more robust and have been looking at StrapPress, Impulse Press and Upplex. Any recommendations for Bootstrap 3 WordPress starter templates with links to examples of sites being built around them?  It needs to be one that is easy to skin as our interns usually set the blogs up.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a lot available if u ask google. I personaly like [bones](http://themble.com/bones/) and [roots](http://roots.io/starter-theme/) if u like to start from the scratch. I have very good expiriences with [gentsthemes](http://gentsthemes.com/themes/) if u like to have something more ready to use.